# restrict number of files to upload for particular users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation

In my property section I have two property types:

1. **Freemium**
2. **Premium**

I want to restrict users to upload only 5 images for **Freemium** property type while for **Premium** properties a user can upload infinitive number images and videos.

Must needed some suggestions.

Here is my image upload part :

```
public function postProperty(PropertyRequest $request)
{

    $user = User::where('id', $request->user->user_id)->first();
    if(!empty($user))
    {
        $data['user_id']        = $user->id;
        $data['type']           = $request->type;
        $data['category']       = $request->category;
        $data['area']           = $request->area;
        $data['price']          = $request->price;
        $data['description']    = $request->description;

        //dd($data);
        $property = Property::create($data);

        //$property['flag'] = false;          // if (flag = false, property = freemium) else (flag = true, property = premium ))

        $urls = new PropertyImage();

        if ($request->hasFile('url'))
        {
            $files = $request->file('url');
            foreach($files as $file)
            {
                $mime = $file->getMimeType();

                //$property['flag'] = $property->account == 1 ? false : true;

                if($mime == 'image/jpeg')
                {
                    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/images/';
                    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
                    $urls->url = '/public/images/' . $fileName;
                    $url_data = [
                        'property_id' => $property->id,
                        'url_type' => 1,
                        'url' => $urls->url,
                    ];


                    $urls->create($url_data);
                }

                elseif($mime == 'video/mp4')
                {
                    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/videos/';
                    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
                    $urls->url = '/public/videos/' . $fileName;
                    $url_data = [
                        'property_id' => $property->id,
                        'url_type' => 2,
                        'url' => $urls->url,
                    ];
                    $urls->create($url_data);
                }
            }
        }
        return Utility::renderJson(trans('api.success'), true, $property, $urls );
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are only using PHP end to upload the images then you could restrict the upload by counting the number of files? Like, throw validation error if the file is greater than 5?

Comment: Restrict to 5 images at once or overall?

Comment: @KiprasT Restrict overall for Freemium type of properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use laravel validation to restrict user to some number of files as shown below
//If user is Freemium then restrict him
if (!$property['flag']) {
$messages = [
    "url.max" => "files can't be more than 3."
 ];

 $this->validate($request, [
        'url' => 'max:3',
    ],$messages);

}
```